# 2 errors messages in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I don't understand why when I launch my project I have 2 errors messages ?

> **[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Class 'Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalizationServiceProvider' not
>   found**

Do you have an idea please I am testing several solutions but without succes so far!

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you follow the steps in https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization? and did you add it to your composer?

Comment: Did you run composer -update to install all of laravels dependencies? Where does the error occure? Where is the second error?

Comment: Hi @anais_stem, we need a bit more information in order to be able to successfully help you. This  seems like an easy fix, and I would love to try and help fix your problem. A bit more detail is needed. Maybe show us your composer.json file and your "providers" and "alias" in your config/app.php file

Comment: @ Tschallacka:  thank you for the url my problem is resolve.

Comment: @ Patrick: it's ok but thank you for your help :-) :)